# Getting error Element should have been "select" but was "div"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have LIST WebElement & I need to select all List Webelement , its not drop down , its list of elements within frame & pane

```
list_xpath = By.xpath(".//div[@class='Class1')]/div[@class='Class2']");
List<WebElement> list = sync on list_xpath 
Count = List.size();
WebElement tempWebElement;
for (int i = 0 ; i <= Count; i++ )

        {
            tempWebElement = list .get(i);
            reporterHelper.log("selectMultiple Starting ...");
            Select select = new Select(tempWebElement);
```

I am getting error as Element should have been "select" but was "div" for select statement

Answer (score 0):

If the element you are trying to pass to the Select object is not a "select" element then it will throw an UnexpectedTagNameException. In the case you outline you are definitely trying to use a "div":

".//div[@class='Class1')]/**div[@class='Class2']**"

So you can't use Select for this. You might be able to build a set of [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) to Ctrl+Click or Shift+Click on all the elements. It really depends on what you are trying to do and how the Webpage behaves.